# How to show all Subversion commits a given user at a given module?

Tags: svn, commit

For example, there is a maven-module is in fact one of the folders in the project structure. How to list all commits affecting this folder and can we somehow filter this list by user name?

Answer (score 1):

> [svn log [URL_PATH]](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html)

and then `grep` the result for a username.

Comment: `svn log` in Subversion 1.8 can `--search`: http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#svn-log-search so grepping may be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

you can press right-click on the folder and subversion menu and then show history. it will display all commits and changes on files in the folder